# Trying to remove a data from table, but without success

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got this code to resolve a bug, I'm working on a health care app, that groups some health care services in a table returning from the back-end. I have a button to remove one of that services from that table, but for some reason that I cant find, just don't work.

In 3 of 4 that services what return I can "delete", and 1 of them, just don't delete.
The bigger problem is if I reload the page, all this services that I tried delete return from the back-end, removing or not from that table.

This is the function that they told me the problem is:

```
async removePlano(cenarioId, operadora, plano) {
      let vm = this;
      vm.recuperaCenario({ id: cenarioId });
      vm.removerPlano({
        plano: plano
      });

      vm.resetRedes();
      vm.resetRegioes();

      let grupos = vm.cenario.operadoras.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
        return [...prev, ...curr.grupos];
      }, []);

      let redes = vm.agrupaRedes(vm.validaPlano(grupos));

      await vm.updateRedes(redes);

      await vm.buscaRegiao({
        uf: operadora.filtros.cidade.uf,
        cidade: '',
        credenciado: operadora.filtros.credenciado ? operadora.filtros.credenciado.tipo + operadora.filtros.credenciado.id : '',
        redes: vm.cenario.redes
      });

      await vm.updateRegioes(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vm.getRegioes)));
```

Comment: Well, about second problem I think is because you don't delete from the database the rows which you just deleted from frontend, you need to send another request to your backend to delete the specified rowId. After you delete a row, try re-fetching the data again.

Comment: If possible, could you please translate names to their English equivalents? I take code as being included in the "posts must be in English" regulation, because if we can't understand the names easily, we can't understand the code easily.